# Fail to run python file in shell direct

Tags: python-3.x

My environment is:`MacOS(sierra-10.12.3) + python3 + zsh + iterm2`

The py file name is `test.py`, which includes following script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
print('hello')
```

and then run `chmod a+x test.py`

but when i run `./test.py`, the zsh bring me to vim.
when i change `test.py` to `test.pyt,then` everything is OK.

Why?

Comment: could you share what's in your PATH.. It seems like python3 is not in your path, I used to think you should starte pythong files with `#!/usr/bin/env python`. So try to locate where python is on your PC and then add the correct line on the beginning of your file, or adapt your PATH.

Comment: Thanks,The python and python3 both in my PATH. I have tried to use #!/usr/bin/env python, it has the same result:the zsh bring me to vim’s edit mode.